# How to forward input file path and name in ASP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am trying to use ASP to upload a JSON file. However, for some strange reason, the control that I use for that only forwards the file name, but not the path.

Here's what I'm doing in my `.cshtml`:

```
    <form asp-page-handler="AddDevices" method="post" >
        <button
            class="btn btn-default"
            id="btn_add_devices"
        >
        Add Devices
        </button>
        <input type="file" name="fileNameAndPath" accept="application/JSON"/>
    </form>
```

...and here's the function that gets called in the corresponding `.cs`:

```
        public void OnPostAddDevices(string fileNameAndPath)
        {
            string jsonString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileNameAndPath);
            [Deserialization]
        }
```

The problem is, that instead of the file name and path that I would like to arrive at that function, only the file name is passed on, so for example if I use the file selector to select the file `C:/TestFiles/TestJson.json`, then in the function `OnPostAddDevices`, the value of the parameter `fileNameAndPath` is only `TestJson.json` instead of what I would need `C:/TestFiles/TestJson.json`.

Naturally, that subsequently results in a `FileNotFoundException`.

What can I do to make the input pass on the full file name with path in this case?

Comment: If you need the file to be uploaded from the client to your server, your approach is not correct. Please read articles about how oy upload files using asp.net and try approaches suggested there.

Comment: you are trying to access an uploading file as it was in your local drive, you didnt need any path,
And you need to make this a form, and upload....
try reading some ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/troubleshoot/aspnet/upload-file-to-web-site

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing now, and what worked to my satisfaction based on the following tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Summed up in short:

In my `index.cshtml`, I added this for the upload button:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <label asp-for="FormFile"></label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <input asp-for="FormFile" type="file">
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <input asp-page-handler="UploadDeviceFile" class="btn" type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

In my `Index.cshtml.cs`, I added this for the uploading logic:

```
        [BindProperty]
        public IFormFile FormFile { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUploadDeviceFileAsync()
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await FormFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

                string jsonString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
                DeviceContainer deviceContainer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeviceContainer>(jsonString);
                DatabaseController.AddAll(deviceContainer.Devices);
            }

            return Page();
        }
```